# Firebase Pagination download whole database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using firebase pagination to limit the firebase database downloads but the firebase console still shows lots of database downloads,

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(country).child(phase);

query = db.orderByChild("random_no").startAt(min).limitToFirst(limit);

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Photo> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Photo>()
                        .setQuery(query, Photo.class)
                        .build();
```

I hope it downloads the whole database before pagination.

Can anyone help how to do firebase pagination without downloading whole database.

Answer (score 0):

If you tell the Firebase data to order/filter its results, it will always do so. It can only do this on the server however, if you've [defined the necessary index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) in the rules of your database. If no such index is found, the SDK will download *all* the nodes at the path, and order/filter them in the application itself. If this happens, it will also log a warning with instructions on what index to add to your logcat output.

So most likely you didn't define an index on `random_no` for `/Posts/$country/$phase` in your database rules.

Comment: I want to index nodes randomly every time users open the app if there is any way to do so by firebase .indexon

Comment: Data is indexed on the server when you define an index. Did you read the link I gave and try it?

Comment: Yes, i understand but what I want is to index the list randomly on the server and then use pagination to the client side.